# Android Update Query Error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am implementing change password in Android using Sqlite.

My query is:

```
try
{
    String update_query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + PWD + "='" + temp_new_pwd + "' WHERE " + EMAIL + " = " + email;
    db.execSQL(update_query);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Changed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And it shows following error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "@abc": syntax error
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa29113f0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for updating a record

```
ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(PWD, new_pwd);
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, EMAIL + "=?", new String[]{email});
```

Comment: Not Working Shows: 'W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa410c60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa005100'

Answer (score 0):

Try this for updating a record
hope  it's working fine...

```
    public void updateQuantity(int id, int quantity) { if (quantity == 0)
        deleteItem(id);
    else {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Constants.QUANTITY, quantity);
        values.put(Constants.DATE_NAME, String.valueOf(new DateTime()));
        int i = db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, values, Constants.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }
}
```